# Calculate the word frequency of a Doc and sort in descending order

Tags: algorithm

In java or C++, what' the most efficient and robust algorithm to deal with the problem? Not considering Map/reduce method, just normal algorithm, HashMap?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, the most efficient method would be to first count the number of occurences of each word using hashmap and then sort the pairs (WordCount, Word) using [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) in total linear time.

In practice, however, if your document is not too big (# of different words <= 10^6 or so), standard c++ sort would be better for the second step. Although complexity would be N log N.

Comment: Second part of a big comment: If you want robustness against collision, you may want to sort words, rather than count them in some structure. That can be done also in N log N and is googleable. You can also look [here] (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/strings/paper.pdf)